# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 form-check - decrease vertical space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the vertical space (make it smaller) between two radio buttons? Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-check">
<label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator margintop0"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Yes</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
<label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="mixed0" name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator margintop0"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">No</span>
</label>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s19bb142/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make `.form-check` `margin-bottom:0;` and also `.custom-control` `margin-bottom: 0;`

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s19bb142/2/)